# How do the turn in transformers step up and step down?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Why do the number of secondary turns have to be greater than the primary coils to step up the voltage and the number secondary turns have to be less than the primary coils to step down the voltage? Wouldn't adding more primary turns just increase the magnetic flux created and increasing the secondary turns increase the area the magnetic field induces current in, resulting in voltage increasing as long as more than 1 turns are added on either side.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do a tremendously crude and simplified argument, just to help you see the general idea. Note that the equations we are all taught, are on the level of this crude approximation; If you actually want to predict things extremely precisely, then you need to upgrade to far better, but also far more complicated, formulæ.

We start by applying Faraday's Law on the wire loops on each side separately, and after quite a lot of abuse and idealisation, we get
$$V=L\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}\tag1$$
of which you need to learn that there is such a thing as [inductance $L,$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) which is likely something you have yet to see before. You can look at just the section on solenoid there, and the important part is that the inductance $L\propto N^2,$ where $N$ is the number of turns. Since the input voltage is fixed, this actually means that, when you double the number of turns, the rate of change of current will be a quarter. This causes the maximum current to also be a quarter. i.e.
$$\tag2
\text{const}=V_\text{in}=L_\text{in}\frac{\mathrm dI_\text{in}}{\mathrm dt}\qquad,\qquad L\propto N^2\qquad\implies\qquad I_\text{in}\propto\frac{V_\text{in}}{N^2_\text{in}}
$$
We need this because then we can use this to see that the magnetic field $B$ that is being setup, will be (see same link same section)
$$B\propto N_\text{in}I_\text{in}\propto\frac{V_\text{in}}{N_\text{in}}$$
That is, when you double the number of turns on the input side, the magnetic field in the transformer actually halves!

On the output side we appeal to the bare Faraday's Law and obtain that it should be
$$V_\text{out}=N_\text{out}BA=\frac{N_\text{out}}{N_\text{in}}V_\text{in}$$
and you can see the result has popped out. Note the crudeness of the derivation, which means that this is only applicable if the number of turns are both very large, so that all the other stray effects are minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you explain theoretically why increasing the number of loops decreases current and increases inductance.

Answer (score 1):

I place myself in the simplest case for which the secondary does not deliver any current.

**For an imposed primary voltage** $v_1$, increasing the number of primary turns **decreases** the magnetic flux per turn $\phi$.
It is easily seen in $v_1= \frac{d\Phi_1}{dt}=N_1\frac{d\phi}{dt}$.

For AC signals the amplitudes are : $V_1 = N_1 \omega \Phi$ or $\Phi =V_1 / N_1 \omega $

For the same flux per $\phi$ turn, increasing the number of secondary turns **increases** the secondary voltage: $v_2= \frac{d\Phi_2}{dt}=N_2\frac{d\phi}{dt} $.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.